# ZMQ_DONTWAIT flag does not work?

Tags: c++, block, zeromq

I am using ZeroMQ for networking in my appliction, the manual states that by providing the `ZMQ_DONTWAIT` flag to the `flags` parameter in `send` or `recv` causes the function to not block the thread. Yet it doesn't work in my case somehow:

```
            std::cout << "a";
            if(ToSend.try_pop(send))
            {
                std::cout << "b";
                local.send(send.data(),send.size(),ZMQ_DONTWAIT);
            }
            std::cout << "c";
            if(local.recv(recv.data(),Networking::max_packet,ZMQ_DONTWAIT))
                std::cout << "Received: " << (char*)recv.data() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "d" << std::endl;
```

this prints:

```
abcdab
```

I made a little class to make things easier:

Client class (striped down from all "unused" stuff, for simplification)

```
class client
{
public:
    client()
    {

    }
    inline bool init(unsigned short threads = 1)
    {
        Running = true;
        context = zmq_init (threads);
        if(context == NULL)
            return false;
        socket = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);
        if(socket == NULL)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    inline int connect(const char * address, unsigned short port)
    {
        return zmq_connect(socket,string_format("tcp://%s:%d",address,port).c_str());
    }
    inline bool send (void *data, size_t len_, int flags_ = 0)
    {
        message_t request (len_);
        memcpy ((void *) request.data (), data, len_);
        int rc = zmq_send (socket, request.data(), request.size(), flags_);
        if (rc >= 0)
            return true;
        if (rc == -1 && zmq_errno () == EAGAIN)
            return false;
        throw error_t ();
    }
    inline bool recv (void * data, size_t len_, int flags_)
    {
        message_t reply(len_);
        int rc = zmq_recv (socket, reply.data(), len_, flags_);
        if (rc >= 0)
        {
            memcpy (data,(void *)reply.data(), reply.size());
            return true;
        }
        if (rc == -1 && zmq_errno () == EAGAIN)return false;
        throw error_t ();
    }
    inline bool IsRunning()
    {
        return Running;
    }
private:
    void * context;
    void * socket;
    std::atomic<bool> Running;
};
```

and here is the worker thread:

```
namespace Data
{
    Concurrency::concurrent_queue <message_t> ToSend;
    void Processor(char * address, unsigned short port, unsigned short threads)
    {
        client local;
        if(!local.init(threads))return;
        if(local.connect(address,port) != 0)return;
        message_t recv(Networking::max_packet);
        message_t send(Networking::max_packet);
        while(local.IsRunning())
        {
            std::cout << "a";
            if(ToSend.try_pop(send))
            {
                std::cout << "b";
                local.send(send.data(),send.size(),ZMQ_DONTWAIT);
            }
            std::cout << "c";
            if(local.recv(recv.data(),Networking::max_packet,ZMQ_DONTWAIT))
                std::cout << "Received: " << (char*)recv.data() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "d" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

The problem exists here somehow. I just don't know why it's not working.

This is how I launch the worker thread:

```
int Thread(char * address, unsigned short port, unsigned short threads)
{
    std::thread data(Data::Processor,address,port,threads);
    data.detach();
    while(!Data::status){}
    return Data::status;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    std::thread s(Server::RUN);

    Client::message_t tosend(14);
    memcpy((void*)tosend.data(),"Hello World !\0",14);

    Client::Data::ToSend.push(tosend);

    std::cout << Client::Thread("127.0.0.1",5555,1) << std::endl;

    s.join();
    return 0;
}
```

This all seems to be correct, so why is recv/send blocking my thread? Why doesn't the flag work?

Comment: Try checking for errors in the send function. "zmq_send() function shall fail with errno set to EAGAIN."

Comment: if it would be an EAGAIN error, then it should not block anything. yet there is no return until there is actually anything to send. and when there is it's succesfully sended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It printed "abcd" and then "ab". This means that the code

```
std::cout << "a";
if(ToSend.try_pop(send))
{
    std::cout << "b";
```

was executed twice although the code you showed at the end of the question implies you only did ToSend.push() once.

Did you attach a debugger to see which thread was hung and what it's callstack is?

- Put the std::cout's behind a mutex/critsect so you know only one thread is writing at a time, and report which thread you are.
- Put each output on it's own line so you don't miss a letter due to buffering.
- If you don't block for data how are you expecting to receive it? Do you have a select/poll/WaitForSingleObject call somewhere?